# EJS Variable Not Displaying

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm working on a random quote machine.  Here's my NODE stuff:

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    var data = "http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1";
    res.render("home", {data: data});
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("SERVER STARTED"); 
});
```

Here's the EJS stuff...

```html
<h1>HELLO</h1>

<li><%= data.data %></li>
```

Everything is going fine, except here's the issue...

**"data.data" in the EJS brackets, it's just nothing.**  Nothing there.  And I've wracked my brain trying to figure out what's going on, but I can't.  Bracket notation didn't work either.  Any ideas what's going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: having the same issue. Ever figured it out?

Answer (score 1):

When you pass stuff to the renderer, the object you pass in the second parameter becomes a 'global' in the ejs rendered page. So when you set something like below:

`res.render("home", { myString: "I like strings" });`

...you can access it by referring to the thing *inside* the passed object:

`<li><%=myString%></li>`

so your data.data is pointing to nothing.

Comment: I have problems when the name of the properties of the data object is in lower camel case. EJS does not render the value of that variable. For example: {"myString": "asd"} does not render the value "asd". But if it were: {"mystring": "asd"} renders it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue and this is my solution. Add `.toJSON()` after `data`:

```
<li><%=data.toJSON().data%></li>
```